# GEO-Location with mobile phone and google maps api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, cordova, geolocation, laravel-4

I have been trying to create a mobile application which will search my own `MySQL database` which has stored information (lat, lng, business name's) about businesses.

Here is a step by step guide on how I am wanting it to work.

```
1). The user will manually input a postcode
2). PHP (laravel) will process the request
3). The Google Maps API will use the Lat, 
Lngs I have stored in my database and display the location closest to the postcode which has been entered.
4). Display the results on the page
```

I am using PhoneGap to create the mobile application and for the PHP framework I am using Laravel.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Now where is your question?

Answer (score 0):

My approach will be to cache the postal codes and lat,lng on to a table. so your requests will be faster.

what you need to do is get the postal code from the user and send it to the google api to get the lat long. then use those values to search the db.

This tutorial on google might help when geting closest the businesses from the db. https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3